# Doctrine2 and Symfony2 - Why this getter mess all the things up?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This snippet of code is driving me crazy.

Suppose that entity on which I've done all this operation have all the members that I recall with getters (either on db that on class file; moreover, onto db, all values were inserted).

```
$this->logger->debug('INV ROOM RATES CAPACITY - $ROOM ID: '.$camera->getId());
$this->logger->debug('INV ROOM RATES CAPACITY - $ROOMCAPACITY: .$camera->getCapienza());
$this->logger->debug('INV ROOM RATES CAPACITY - CAMERA DB ID: '.$camera->getId());
```

This outputs the following

```
[2013-02-11 14:17:32] app.DEBUG: INV ROOM RATES CAPACITY - $ROOM ID: 14 [] []
[2013-02-11 14:17:32] app.DEBUG: INV ROOM RATES CAPACITY - $ROOMCAPACITY:  [] []
[2013-02-11 14:17:32] app.DEBUG: INV ROOM RATES CAPACITY - CAMERA DB ID:  [] []
```

It seems that `->getCapienza()` method is messing all the things up (*second getter on the same object, doesn't return previous value*).
Obviously, no error or exceptions are raised.

What's going on here? Any ideas? I'm stuck since hours ....

## EDIT

```
public function getCapienza()
{
    return $this->capienza;
}
```

Comment: Could you post `getCapienza()` code?

Comment: @PeterM: is what doctrine setted itself, so is a return of a class member, but ok, I'll update.
Take a look at the update

Comment: Did you try logging the SQL queries going to your database?

Comment: @Ocramius: have I *explicitly* log them, or are logged automatically?

Comment: If you are using Symfony2, then there's a profiler component for it. Otherwise, you can always set an SQL logger on the connection as of http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#configuration-options

Comment: @Ocramius yes, I know that there is the profiler, but it seems not to log those operation (are ajax calls). What leaves me perplexed is that first getter is working well but second one isn't.....

Comment: Yes, this looks like wrong lazy initialization of your object. Validate your mappings and somehow try to track the SQL queries (manually set a DebugStack logger - https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Logging/DebugStack.php )

Comment: @Ocramius: consulting "canonical" logs, it seems that doctrine ask for whole $camera object (I do it the line above first log) and if I run that query into a RDBMS, it shows me what I expected to have in output

Comment: @Ocramius: forgot to say that, somewhere in code just before those operation and for object cloning purpose, i call a `clear()` operation on my entity_manager. Could this be involved with this behaviour? (on "cloned" [refetched] object, I can do all this operation but on the "starting" object, them fails

Comment: @Ocramius let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24321/discussion-between-doncallisto-and-ocramius)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just told me that you are clearing the EntityManager sometimes, I digged into it a bit further.

It is a known issue that will be fixed in Doctrine ORM 2.4 when https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/406 is merged.

The issue happens because of following piece of code: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1724-L1780

Basically, it is impossible to merge or generally use proxies that are detached from an EntityManager (you should have lazy-loaded them before).

The problem you are experiencing is related with http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1734

A temporary solution is to re-fetch the data you want to use instead of recycling detached instances.